# Paypal mass payment intergration

Tags: php, paypal

I have a website where buyers make payments to seller in order to do a job for them. I have integrated the first part where the buyer makes payment to a particular buyer with pay pal express checkout.However,i want each seller to be able to withdraw his or her money from his or her account at the end of each billing month on click withdraw with pay pal.I need a person who can kindly direct me on how to go about it with php.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout PayPal Payouts.  Perfect for paying out marketplace sellers.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/